# jQuery mouseover on dynamic objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently trying to achieve a slight fade while doing a mouse-over on a object,
in this case i'm making a photo gallery, each photo has the ID "fotoblok" and a dynamic class ("foto"+photonumber, example: foto1 or foto55)

```
$("#fotoblok").mouseover(function(){
$(this).animate({opacity: 0.5});
});

$("#fotoblok").mouseout(function(){
$(this).animate({opacity: 1});
});
```

This is my current jQuery code, however this only changes the first photo and not all following ones, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: you can't use duplicate `id`, id should be `unique` and belongs to only one element at a time

Comment: You've got it backwards. They should all have the same class `fotoblock`, and unique IDs `foto+number`. Then you can use the selector `$(".fotoblock")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the ids have to be unique.. But classes can be dupes..

You've badly designed your markup. But any way, you would use event-delegation:

```
$('[class^="foto"]').on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.5
        });
    }
    mouseout: function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: I have changed my code, the ID's of the blocks are now "fotoblok" + photonumber, and I class the desired css behind it to a class.. Also your code seems to be the solution,  thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use different JQuery selector. Try this:

```
$("div[id^='foto'],div[id*=' foto']")
```

This will be find classes that start with "foto" and classes that contains "foto"

Comment: Currently, the OP is using IDs to refer to a set of elements, not classes.

Answer (score 0):

An ID is meant to be unique: it refers to *one* element.

Classes refer to multiple elements and should be used in cases like this.

So, your images should all have `fotoblok` as the class:

```
<img class="fotoblock"/>
```

Then, refer to the classes in your event handler:

```
$(".fotoblok").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5});
});

$(".fotoblok").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1});
});
```

Also, this is repetitive code. To simplify it, use [`.hover()`](//api.jquery.com/hover), which handles both `mouseenter` and `mouseexit` events:

```
$(".fotoblok").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5});
}),function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1});
});
```

Comment: I got told to do this already, so I did, it works fine now. Thanks!